# How to find identical index between columns that has different number of items in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, i have two datetime columns :

```
col1 = [2019-01-01 03:00:00,
        2019-01-01 03:01:00,
        2019-01-01 03:02:00]

col2 = [2019-01-01 02:59:00, 
        2019-01-01 03:00:00, 
        2019-01-01 03:01:00, 
        2019-01-01 03:02:00, 
        2019-01-01 03:03:00]
```

Each has index of [0, 1, 2] and [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

So, what I want to get is [1, 2, 3], which is index of col2 (*overlapped elements with col1*).

Below is my code and it doesn't work:

```
ind = []
for x in range(len(col1)):
    rw = np.where(col2 == col1[x])
    ind.append(int(rw[0]))
```

Is there any simple way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oneliner using `enumerate`:

```
[i for i, t in enumerate(col2) if t in col1]
# [1,2,3]
```

You can also use `pandas.Series.isin`:

```
import pandas as pd

col1 = pd.Series(["2019-01-01 03:00:00",
        "2019-01-01 03:01:00",
        "2019-01-01 03:02:00"])

col2 = pd.Series(["2019-01-01 02:59:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:00:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:01:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:02:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:03:00"])
col2.index[col2.isin(col1)].tolist()
# [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Thank you Chris!! This is exactly what I want to know! :]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use numpy to solve this problem then you could just loop through one list and check if each element exists in the other list.

```
>>> col1 = ["2019-01-01 03:00:00",
        "2019-01-01 03:01:00",
        "2019-01-01 03:02:00"]
>>> col2 = ["2019-01-01 02:59:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:00:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:01:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:02:00", 
        "2019-01-01 03:03:00"]
>>> ind = []
>>> for element in col1:
    if element in col2:
        ind.append(element)


>>> print(ind)
['2019-01-01 03:00:00', '2019-01-01 03:01:00', '2019-01-01 03:02:00']
```

Comment: That's what i wanted to do at first time! Although it requires little more times(the size of my column is more than 500,000), i think it's nice way to! Thanks for comment :)